# Spring async events and Spring security context

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-security, event-handling

**Hey**

I have found some code that allow to use `spring events` in `async` way by overriding the code `ApplicationEventMulticaster`, so each `listener` will run its in own thread.  [example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276009/how-to-configure-async-and-sync-event-publishers-using-spring)

My question is:

Does the security context will be the same as the `publisher thread`? or i have to to pass `user logged id` to each `publisher`

Thanks,

Oak

## Edit:

Going through the docs:

### i have found

> Some applications aren't entirely suitable for using a ThreadLocal, because of the specific way they work with threads. For example, a Swing client might want all threads in a Java Virtual Machine to use the same security context. SecurityContextHolder can be configured with a strategy on startup to specify how you would like the context to be stored. For a standalone application you would use the SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL strategy. Other applications might want to have threads spawned by the secure thread also assume the same security identity. This is achieved by using SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL. You can change the mode from the default SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL in two ways. The first is to set a system property, the second is to call a static method on SecurityContextHolder. Most applications won't need to change from the default, but if you do, take a look at the JavaDocs for SecurityContextHolder to learn more.

So it seems that if one set up 
`SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` is should work

My question is: does anyone have experience with this kind of configuration?

Comment: new `securityContext` will be created for new asych thread If you need to keep the same `SecurityContext` you are responsible for passing present `SecurityContext` to `SecurityContextHolder` in new thread that will assign it to   `ThreadLoacal` in this situation

Comment: also you should clear `SecurityContextHolder` after thread is done

Comment: @user1289300, the thanks for answering did you try it?  i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

combining the `doc` from the `question` and **@viator** remark at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468965/1211174

### Setup the rule to inherit security context from the thread

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"        p:targetClass="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"
    p:targetMethod="setStrategyName" p:arguments="MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL" />
```

### Make sure spring event will be asynced

```
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster"
    class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster">
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```