# (Spring) Filtering multicasters based on event type

Tags: spring, events, javabeans, code-injection, listeners

I have a custom event, which I call LoginEvent (which extends ApplicationEvent) defined. I have defined a few listeners which are listening to this event. I have figured our how to make the event listeners asynchronous (by changing the taskExecutor within eventMulticaster). This is how I have made my events to be thrown in an asynchronous manner.

```
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster" class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster"> 
    <property name="taskExecutor" > <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" 
    /> </property> </bean>
```

But from what I understand, this is going to force ALL of my custom events go asynchronous. I don't want to do that if I can have a way to chose different taskExecutors for different types of events (ir, categorize my Events as Sync ans async). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post that explains how to configure synchronous and asynchronous event publishers

http://learningviacode.blogspot.ae/2012/08/publishing-events-asynchronously.html

SO question:

[How to configure Async and Sync Event publishers using spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276009/how-to-configure-async-and-sync-event-publishers-using-spring)