# Spring boot : @Async is not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

If anyone has experienced this issue before: I have a springboot application with version 2.1.1.RELEASE.

In this application, I have a controller that calls one service which calls an email services, so the relation is like:

```
controller -> businessLogicService -> emailService
```

In the `emailService`, I have the `sendMail` method tagged with `@Async`, and I have enabled it by putting `@EnableAsync` in the main application.

Currently the method is still running on the main thread which is blocking the operation until it finishes.

I have looked into the issue deeply but still no luck

One of the strange exercises I have done is to clone the 3 services
but this time the `@Async` worked fine, so somehow something is wrong with the other ones.

Putting in mind the application is huge & the email service is autowired in a lot of places the same for the `businessLogicService`

Comment: Why don't you look at all the differences between your working and non-working versions.

Comment: they are exactly the same ( i just copy pasted and renamed them )
and they are in the same project

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following configuration class to your application and tell whether it works or not:

```java
/**
 * Enables asynchronous task management. Implements {@link AsyncConfigurer} to allow
 * event publishing operations being executed both synchronously and asynchronously.
 */
@EnableAsync
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    /*
     * Implementing AsyncConfigurer allows to determine an Executor for asynchronous operations only. This way it is
     * sufficient to simply annotate desired methods with @Async for async treatment, event publishing tasks included.
     *
     * In contrast, providing an ApplicationEventMulticaster would cause all event publishing tasks to be executed
     * asynchronously by default. To be able to execute synchronous tasks nevertheless, we would have to adapt
     * ApplicationEventMulticaster#multicastEvent() accordingly: for example, we could decide by means of a marker
     * interface to which executor the task should get passed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57929153).
     */

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(8);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(32);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(64);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("DallasMultipassExecutor-");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

Comment: will give it a try and post the results here

Comment: not working .. put in mind we are using spring 2.1.1.Release so ProxyBeanMethods was not there

Comment: Not using `proyBeanMethods` shouldn't make any difference. But since this solution is not working I can't help further. Without any code examples provided by you I think someone can only guess, or you may have luck and someone had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the @Async method from within the same class won't work, you must call that method from diffrent class.

Comment: am calling it from a diff class

Comment: @SherifMoShalaby can you maybe edit you question with code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If EmailService has a method sendMail which is async, it should be called directly in businessLogicService class method. Something like this

```
BusinessLogicService { 
  foo(){
   emailService.sendMail();
  }
}
```

If some other method is being called in businessLogicService, try making that async.